# Why no general linear group with Lorentz signature?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

The spin group can be ${\rm Spin}(n-k,k)$ and the orthogonal group $O(n-k,k)$, allowing for Riemannien and Lorentzian signature. But I have never seen the concept applied to the general linear group : $GL(n-k,k,\mathbb{F})$ is never mentioned. Instead we have $GL(n,\mathbb{F})$. Are all signatures contained in the $GL$ group? For instance are all $SO(2)$ and $SO(1,1)$ and ${\rm Spin}(2)$ and ${\rm Spin}(1,1)$ contained in $GL(2)$?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my question was obvious; since SO(2), SO(1,1), Spin(2) and Spin(1,1) are invertible, then by necessity they are in GL(2).

Comment: Yes, they're all in $GL$ already, there's no need to mention a signature when it comes to $GL$.

Comment: The definitions of the orthogonal, spin, and symplectic groups all involve a bilinear form, and so the signature of the form is relevant to the nature of the group. But the definition of the general linear group doesn't depend on such a form. (I think this is what @QiaochuYuan meant by "no need to mention", but I want to emphasize that there's no use mentioning a signature --- it's simply irrelevant.)